# Ubuntu re-open background process in terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Python application `SERVER.py` that i am running in the background using:

```
screen -d -m python3 server.py
```

I would like to be able to re-open this background process in the terminal.

Comment: If `python` is the only background process, simply type `fg`. If there are several background tasks, type `jobs`, then `fg %N`, where `N` is the index of the `python` task.

Comment: fg returns no such job. and jobs doesnt do anything. i assure you my application is running though.

Comment: I've not used `screen` before, but some tests showed that, once launched, `screen` appears in capitals in the process list, so `ps -efl|grep SCREEN` will find it, and `screen -r PID` (where `PID` is the value from the `ps` output) will restore it. If your version does not appear in capitals, you may need to use `ps -efl|grep -i screen` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -d -m python3 server.py
screen -ls
screen -r [session] (reatta
screen -X -S [session # you want to kill] quit
```